# Error:(40, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

Tags: android-studio

I still cant get to solve this problem, in my androidManifest.xml i have: im working in android studio, and still cant find any answer, please help!!! this is to display a map fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.presley.valle.jobme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.presley.valle.jobme.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value=****************************MY_KEY" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 14):

Solved, is a little bit confusing doing it in android studio, but all i did was:
go to:

```
-> File
-> project structure
-> app 
-> dependencies 
-> click on + 
-> library dependency
-> select play-services (October 2015: com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0)

-> Rebuild
```

Problem solved!
i could have done it the way you say, but what if is not the version im pointing.
Thanks

Comment: After clicking on +->  select com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71 #from the Library dependency

Answer (score 5):

It looks, that you haven't added Google Play Services library to project. In build.gradle in dependencies section add:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`

(or any other version of this lib. 5.0.89 is just an example)